# How do you edit Windows10 Directory Junctions (links to folders) from Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

(it's not a duplicate, but hey. I guess as per some of the comments, the answer is "you can't, Microsoft hasn't made it possible". It's annoying to see people incorrectly directed to a wrong resource at the top of the page, but I don't have any options for un-breaking the wrong filing, so I'll leave it here. Sorry, future visitors!)

I have created some hard links (Directory Junctions) - they show up in Windows File Explorer with a little shortcut-like icon overlaid on the normal folder icon.

But how do we edit them (and implicitly: see where they are pointing) in Windows Explorer?

Worst case, dropping down to the command line, even mklink doesn't appear to have editing as an option (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) and I can't find anything in Windows File Explorer to see info on them (let alone edit it).

Do you have to manually delete each one and recreate it, rather than edit it?

Is there literally nothing in MS's own file explorer to view them? (the shell extensions I could find don't show where they point to, and don't let you destroy them, but do let you create them).

Comment: Until now Microsoft never had include any UI for creating/viewing junctions/soft-/hardlinks in the WIndows Explorer. There are third party tools like [Link Shell Ext](https://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html) that add this functionality to Windows Explorer.

Comment: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/ntfs_links_view.html

Comment: Similar question>>>https://superuser.com/questions/823959/how-to-view-all-the-symbolic-links-junction-points-hard-links-in-a-folder-using

Comment: "Hard links" are a different thing. Junctions should be referred to as "soft links", along with symbolic links, which they closely resemble.

Comment: @kreemoweet fixed the title

Comment: If anyone knows how to remove the ugly (and wrong) banner at the top of the question, that's going to misdirect everyone who googles this for the next N years ... please let me know. As far as I can tell I can't even object to the banner - my only option is to delete the question (!).

Comment: Please read the Help section to learn more about how Superuser works. You used the wrong words to describe your situation, we rightly pointed out the question you had asked had already been asked and answered. You realized you had mischaraterized your issue and have made your question more clear. Now, the wheels of the process turns and if enough members of the community agree your question may be reopened.