# File Explorer Shows Different Folder Name Than Actual, Causes Network Share Issue

Tags: windows-10, command-line, windows-explorer, shared-folders, desktop.ini

I am having a similar issue as the original poster [here](https://superuser.com/questions/381110/windows-explorer-sees-different-file-name-from-cmd/381159#381159) after going from a Windows 7 Professional system to Windows 10 Professional.  I have not been able to identify/solve my issue. My issue is my profile folder (C:\users\%username%) that is supposed to show my username, but is displayed as "Music."

[image: Image of folders as displayed in C:\Users]

I have a desktop computer (the subject computer) where all of my personal folders/files are primarily stored. These folders are shared, but permissions are restricted to my username. I then change the target of my personal folders on my laptop computer to these shared folders on the desktop and make them available offline.

Like the original poster of the aforementioned thread, I copied/pasted my old documents/music/pictures/etc. from my old computer to the respective sub-folder of the profile folder on the new computer. However, my old computer never referenced the profile folder as "Music" and even after removing the "Read only" attribute from all folders and subfolders in the profile directory, this problem persists for me. Further, desktop.ini is not visible within the users folder or the profile folder even with hidden files/folders shown, though it is able to be opened using the full address from within Notepad.  However, since it is not visible, I cannot manually delete it from within Explorer.  Also, the command prompt 'del /f filename' returns "Could Not Find {filename}" in both instances.

Worse, the laptop computer synchronizes the folder with the share name "music" (on the desktop, that is C:\users\%username%\Music) as though it is the profile folder (C:\users\%username%).

I think I may have inadvertently shared the profile folder on the desktop with the share name of "Music" before I discovered the mistake, "unshared" it, and associated that share name with the correct folder (C:\Users\%username%\Music). But why in Windows 10 the system then gives this folder an alternative display name AND my second computer continues to synchronize with the profile folder even though a different folder has that share name and address, are questions I have not found answers to.

Thanks for any help!

Z

Answer (score 1):

Through another support page, this issue has been resolved.

https://answers.microsoft.com/thread/0974274c-821b-4b56-af08-79f49966097c

Apparently, my tricks to delete the desktop.ini file in command prompt did not work.  Instead, the extension was renamed using command prompt as an administrator, which disabled the functionality of the desktop.ini file.  File Explorer operations returned to normal afterwards.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to delete the desktop.ini file

A simple `del desktop.ini` normally won't work as the file is locked/hidden via attributes
(The commands below might have to be executed as admin if permissions are missing)

The command to unlock / unhide:

```
attrib   *.ini    -s   -h   -r
```

and move:

```
ren  desktop.ini  *.bad
```

or delete:

```
del desktop.ini
```

If one doesn't care - the command to nuke all `desktop.ini` in a directory recursively:

```
del /s /ah desktop.ini
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep the fixes current, here are **PowerShell** equivalents:

To remove the `ReadOnly` attribute on the UserProfile folder:

```
(gi $Home).Attributes -= 'ReadOnly' # $Home can be modifed to literal path.
```

and to delete a `desktop.ini` file:

```
ri "$Home\desktop.ini" -force
```